# Background image is full height on desktop but not on mobile

Tags: css

My background image is full screen and looks fine on desktop, however, on mobile it is not full height. The image is the full width of the screen just not the height.

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(99, 177, 242, 0.5),rgba(99, 177, 242, 0.5)), url('../images/background.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
    height: 1px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Does anybody know why this might happen?

Comment: Thanks for providing your CSS, but can you please provide the relevant HTML as well? It's rather difficult to answer this question without being able to see how your existing page is rendered. It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: if this is only your CSS, you are relying on the background propagation ... so better add this to the body `margin:0;min-height:100vh`

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif!